# Reflection on a matched transmission line

Tags: rf, transmission-line, impedance-matching, reflection

A matched load with source using a transmission line (assume real load and matched using quarter wave transformer) should not have any reflection ideally.

But we can see that the load impedance is not same as characteristic impedance of the quarter wave transformer, so when we calculate Gamma L (Γ<sub>L</sub>)  at the load, it shows there is reflection.

I would like to understand what's the difference between load reflection coefficient and the actual reflection on the line.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300548/quarter-wavelength-matching-missing-reflections

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quarter Wavelength Matching : Missing Reflections?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300548/quarter-wavelength-matching-missing-reflections)

Comment: Can we close this? I don't have the reputation to cast closing votes.